# What is the value of a?

Tags: fractions

$\frac{8−i}{3−2i}$

If the expression above is rewritten in the form a+bi, where a and b are real numbers, what is the value of a?

All I know is that it equals $\frac{8-i}{3-2i}$ times $\frac{3+2i}{3+2i}$ and then i did not know what to do

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Well that would mean it is $\frac{(8-i)(3+2i)}{(3-2i)(3+2i)}$.  And you ought to know that $(A+B)(C+D) = AC +AD +BC +BD$.  So you should be able to expand the numerator and denominator out.  There's a "trick" that $i^2 = -1$ but other than that.... it's just like any other multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note,

$$\frac{8−i}{3−2i}=\frac{8-i}{3-2i}\cdot\frac{3+2i}{3+2i}=\frac{(24+2)+(16-3)i}{3^2-(2i)^2}=\frac{26+13i}{13}=2+i$$

Comment: Yes, but how did you get the bracketed fraction? That is what I was struggling on. To simplify the two fractions. Any way, can you tell me?

Comment: @102152111 - Use $(a-b)(a+b)= a^2-b^2$ for the denominator

Comment: yes! helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This can be written as
$$8 +(-\tfrac13)i +(-2)i.$$
Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

$(8-i)(3+2i)$ will be $24+16i-3i+2$ because $i×i=-1$
And $(3-2i)(3+2i)$ [using the identity $(x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$] will be $9+4=13$ and then you can separate the fractions with the denominator $13$ and you will get the value of a which will be $26/13=2$.

Comment: That helps a lot